# the phonegap navigator.globalization.stringToDate with iOS

Tags: globalization, string-to-datetime

I am using phonegap build 2.9 and 3.1 and ipad mini 7.04

```
navigator.globalization.stringToDate('9/25/2012',function(date)
 { alert('success');},function () { alert('fail'); },{selector:'date'});
```

**in Android**

- when I set selector "date", it will alert "success"
- when I set selector "time", it will alert "fail"
- when I set selector "date and time", it will alert "fail"

**in iOS**

- when I set selector "date", it will also alert "fail"
- when I set selector "time", it will alert "fail"
- when I set selector "date and time", it will alert "fail"

Why is it that setting "date" will be "success" in Android, but "date" will "fail" in iOS?

Comment: Worked just fine for me on iOS.